# What's the reason behind having LVM activation mode set to degraded by default?

Tags: lvm

Out of curiosity, why is this

```
root@pve:~# lvmconfig --type default activation/activation_mode
activation_mode="degraded"
```

degraded, by default?

Doesn't this configuration expose users to the risk of data loss?
Say user has a raid1, with 1 mirror and one disk goes faulty. The uses will not be aware of the failure unless he manually checks in the logs, because the raid will keep working.
Then after a while finally the second disk fails, and only now the user will notice the failures, but is too late because all mirrors are lost.

As opposed to if activation mode was set to complete by default, the user would be aware of the disk failure right away since the raid would stop working, and would have a chance to recover the data from the remaining mirror.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

A watchful sysadmin will detect a drive failure via their monitoring tools, and replace it. Little to no availability disruption.

Should a disk completely fail, then the LV need to be activated, degraded means the volumes may be put in service immediately. Even if a spare is not at hand. Activate degraded is an option, change if if you like.

A competent sysadmin will have tested backup restores from different media. Arrays cannot protect valuable data against all types of failure.

Comment: I did set the activation mode to complete and I'm glad I noticed this now. If a disk fails I want it to stop working immediately until replaced. I don't want to look in logs every day for disk failures. I got better things to do. It blows my mind that degraded is the default setting.